# Saving ArrayList to Text File

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I have been trying to get an ArrayList to save to a file. I can see it is creating the text file, but nothing is placed inside the text file, just blank.

Here is the main code with the ArrayList,Switch with option to save.

```
static int input, selection, i = 1;
static ArrayList<Animals> a;

// Main Method
public static void main(String[] args){

    // Create an ArrayList that holds different animals
    a = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add(new Animals(i++, "Bear", "Vertebrate", "Mammal"));
    a.add(new Animals(i++, "Snake", "Invertebrate", "Reptile"));
    a.add(new Animals(i++, "Dog", "Vertebrate", "Mammal"));
    a.add(new Animals(i++, "Starfish", "Invertebrates", "Fish"));

    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("1: View List\n2: Delete Item\n3: Add Item\n4: Edit Item\n5: Save File\n0: Exit");
            selection = scanner.nextInt();
            if(selection != 0){
                switch (selection) {
                    case 1:
                        ViewList.view();
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Delete.deleteItem();
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Add.addItem();
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Edit.editItem();
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Save.saveToFile("animals.txt", a);
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        break;
```

This is what I have written to handle file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Save extends ALProgram{
     public static void saveToFile(String fileName, ArrayList list){
            Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);
            try{
                System.out.println("File Saved");
                Files.write(filePath, list, Charset.defaultCharset());
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }
}
```

Here is Animal Class

```
class Animals {

public int id;
public String type, vertebrate, aclass;

public Animals(int id, String type, String vertebrate, String aclass) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.vertebrate = vertebrate;
    this.aclass = aclass;

}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getVert() {
    return vertebrate;
}

public String getaclass() {
    return aclass;
}

}
```

Comment: If you use generics on the parameter `ArrayList` for `saveToFile` it will reveal a type error on `Files.write` which is causing the problem.

Comment: Please provide "Animals" class for me and I will help you with the solution.

Comment: @NulledCoder I added class to edit

Comment: @4castle is the error  I am looking for:   "The method write(Path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>, Charset, OpenOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path, ArrayList<capture#1-of ?>, Charset)"

Comment: Yes, that's the correct error. The issue is that it's meant to be passed a `List` of objects which extend `CharSequence`. You should probably iterate over the list and create another list filled with string values that represent each `Animal`.

Comment: By saving to file, you mean just printing the contents to file or making loadable back into the application? What do you expect to see in the file?

Comment: @kazenorin You are correct, printing contents to file.

Comment: @4castle will look over and give it a go.

Comment: I wonder why this write function need an Iterable object which implements CharSequence. Will ask it separately though.

Comment: @Gaurava Look at the docs for [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). It's so that it can write each CharSequence (which is a super of String), to the file as a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two changes:

1. Your class need to implement CharSequence to be eligible to be passed to Files.write.
2. You need to over-ride toString method to specify how your contents look like when saved.
   I can see output after above two changes.

   ```
       class Animals implements CharSequence {

           public int id;
           public String type, vertebrate, aclass;

   public Animals(int id,String type,String vertebrate,String aclass) {
   this.id = id;
   this.type = type;
   this.vertebrate = vertebrate;
               this.aclass = aclass;
           }

           public int getID() {
               return id;
           }

           public String getType() {
               return type;
           }

           public String getVert() {
               return vertebrate;
           }

           public String getaclass() {
               return aclass;
           }

           @Override
           public int length() {
               return toString().length();
           }

           @Override
           public char charAt(int index) {
               return toString().charAt(index);
           }

           @Override
           public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
               return toString().subSequence(start, end);
           }

           /* (non-Javadoc)
            * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
            */
           @Override
           public String toString() {
               return "Animals [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + ", vertebrate=" + vertebrate + ", aclass=" + aclass + "]";
           }


           }
   ```

Comment: That works perfect, I see a lot better what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, first one, you cannot just save it by casting it to string.
You need to get each element, build a string obly then write it down to file.
Here's an example:

```
public static void saveToFile(String fileName, ArrayList<Animal> list){

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<=list.size(); i++) {
Animal lAn = list.get(i);
sb.Append("Animal ID: "+lAn.getID()+"; Animal type: "+lAn.getType()+"; Animal vert: "+lAn.getVert()+"; Animal aclass: "+lAn.getaclass()+"\r\n");
}

try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) { out.print(sb.toString()); }

} catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); } }
```

Try it. Theres also could be some mistakes/mispelling because I wrote this code from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You could write only `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`, so change you code like below.

Please make sure to override `toString` method of `Animal` class

```
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    Animal a1 = new Animal(1L, "XYZ", "A2B");
    Animal a2 = new Animal(2L, "ABC", "IJK");
    animals.add(a1);
    animals.add(a2);
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
        strings.add(animal.toString());
    }
    Files.write(Paths.get("output.out"), strings, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: You would print hashes to the file this way.

Comment: i have overridden `toString` forgot to mention, thanks, edited answer